# .htaccess redirect

Tags: .htaccess, redirect, apache2, mod-rewrite, http-status-code-404

Необходимо сделать редирект на другой хост, если файла нет (т.е. при 404), без сохранения всего урл. Если файл есть на данном хосте, редирект делать не нужно:

localhost/test/test2/test.php -> newhost.com/test.php 
localhost/test/test2/test3/test123.php -> newhost.com/test123.php

Получилось сделать следующее:

```html
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://newhost.com/$1
```

проблема в том, что редирект идет не в корень. Работает так:
localhost/test/test2/test.php -> newhost.com/test2/test.php

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule (\w+\.php)$ http://newhost.com/$1
```

Comment: То что нужно, спасибо!

Comment: @YevgeniyM пожалуйста )

Comment: Есть проблема, если в названии файла есть - и ., он обрещает по последнему символ, например:
in-+7777777777-7777777777-20180313-56456-5464645656.11583.wav

редиректит на 11583.wav

подскажите, как это исправить

Comment: Ну можно более "широкий" шаблон использовать вместо `\w+`. Например, так `[a-zA-Z0-9-\+\.]+\.\w+`